# Why the bufferedREader is close after call to another funcation. How can I write that I can read after callin another function

Tags: java, reader

Why is `BufferedReader` closed after calling another method? How can I read after calling another method? After execution of method `add()` the reader is closed and reader into main throwing `NullPointerException`(closed).

Quweston was solved. Into another method I made readers too and after calling method with reader(into try with resorces) both reader closed.
I solve this by deleting all readers and made one into one static methos with static reader for all programm.

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReaderIn reader = new ReaderIn();
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Input the action (add, remove, import, export, ask, exit):");
            String switchTrigger = null;
            try {
                switchTrigger = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (switchTrigger == null) {
                System.out.println("SwitchTrigger is null.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            switch (switchTrigger) {
                case "add":
                    add();
                    break;
                case "remove":
                    remove();
                    break;
                case "import":
                    importCardFromFile();
                    break;
                case "export":
                    export();
                    break;
                case "ask":
                    ask();
                    break;
                case "exit":
                    System.out.println("Bye bye!");
                    System.exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry question is done.

Comment: `switchTrigger = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))` — Warning: you are creating a new reader on each loop iteration. You should move this line outside of the loop.

Comment: @ГазизВалитов If you solved the problem then you can post your solution as an answer to your own question or simply delete the question.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. No `NullPointerException`. Of-course you didn't post a [mcve] so I added dummy methods `add`, `ask`, `export`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by deleting Reader into another methods (into add(), remove()) and creat one method with one reader for all program.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).